# VueJS - Flexed columns / fitting table to any width of the screen in ag-grid-vue

Tags: vue.js, width, ag-grid

I am using Ag-grid in order to display table, i am looking to make my table responsive.

So i am trying to fit the whole table/ whole columns to what ever the width of the screen is:

- If the width of the screen is less than 500px only then i want to make the the x-axis scrollable, otherwise the entire table/ entire columns should fit the screen.

Here is the codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-khorana-bw55b

Initially the table was leaving space like this:

[image]

I also tried this in mounted:

```
mounted () {
    this.gridApi = this.gridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit()
}
```

I get below image when i reduce the width of the screen and when i have used sizeColumnsToFit():

[image]

But the sizeColumnsToFit() works fine when the width of the screen is full.

I also referred the documentation of ag-grid, and found out the below link:

https://plnkr.co/edit/YG7be1X8kAgeSEas, this is what i am looking for, and i also tried the same as example but don't know why i could not make my table responsive like that.

So, please help me in making my table fit to what ever the width of the screen is. As the width keeps decreasing and if its less than 500px only then i want to make it scrollable. Then, i also want to reduce the space between columns, so it becomes easy to fit the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the grid event `gridSizeChanged` to call a function each time your grid size changes. In this function, call `sizeColumnsToFit` to auto size your columns if your grid size is more than 500px, else, resize each of the columns to a more reasonable width each, e.g. 300px;

```
onGridSizeChanged(params) {
      if (params.clientWidth > 500) {
        this.gridApi.sizeColumnsToFit();
      } else {
        this.columnDefs.forEach(x => {
          x.width = 300;
        });
        this.gridApi.setColumnDefs(this.columnDefs);
      }
    },
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-vue-hello-world-pntgdn?file=app.js).

In order to reduce the space between the columns, use `defaultColDef` to remove the padding from the cells, and set the padding to 0 for the ag-header-cell class for the headers

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-vue-hello-world-vvjpnh?file=style.css).

Comment: Thank you so much :) ,now how can i reduce the space between columns ?

Comment: use `defaultColDef` to remove the padding from the cells, and set the padding to 0 for the `ag-header-cell` class for the headers, [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-vue-hello-world-vvjpnh?file=style.css).